# Vuetify v-data-table not responsive when using v-slot:body

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Vuetify v-data-table not stacking on mobile devices when using v-slot:body

How can I get the data table to stack if it implements the body v-slot? As can be seen in the Vuetify documentation this is how a normal v-data-table behaves:

[image: Stacked table]

And this is how it behaves when using body slot:

[image: Not stacked table]

Thank you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The default `body` [implementation](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VDataTable/VDataTable.ts#L448) of `v-data-table` has two components for the table rows - `Row` and `MobileRow`. When the page's width is under 600px, `MobileRow` is used.

By using the `body` slot, the default implementation is discarded, along with the mobile logic, so you must supply your own. Fortunately, there's a handy helper [class](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/display#display) we can use to easily switch styling depending on the current page size.

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/srdecny/pen/wvvvYVq) with a sketch up of the solution. The relevant part:

```
  <template v-slot:body="props">
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="item in props.items">
        <td class="d-block d-sm-table-cell" v-for="field in Object.keys(item)">
          {{item[field]}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </template>
```

For more precise styling, you might want to use the visibility helper [classes](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/display#visibility) and have two separate implementations for the table rows - just like the default implementation.

Comment: Nice example on how to use these helper classes.